# Woocommerce - Add multiple prices to one product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Im looking for a way to add several prices for a single product in WooCommerce, I'm using version 2.6.11.

For example:

**Product: Beer Fest**

***Prices:***

**Pre-sale:** $10
**Same-Day:** $30
**VIP:** $100

Could anyone point me on the right direction?

Comment: Please post the code you have tried

Answer (score 4):

You can use Variations.
Just declare a Product as "Variable", define an attribute as "Prices" and each value of that attribute is going to be "Pre-sale|Same-Day|VIP".

In Variations just click in "Use Attributes as Variations", That way you can declare a price for each attribute.
Pre-sale : $10
Same-Day : $30
VIP : $100

A quick way of how it will display.(It may vary depending on your theme)
[image]

Comment: Worked perfectly Syntax_Error++

Answer (score 1):

I believe you'll want to make your Beer Fest product a "variable Product". This allows for variations in price, images, etc.

Documentation for WooCommerce Variable Products:
https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/variable-product/